# Knex.js with Postgres returns boolean fields as "0" or "1" instead of booleans

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

When I query with Knex.js a Postgres database boolean fields it returns the result as `"0"` or `"1"` (as strings) instead of the boolean values `true` and `false`.

Is there a way to make Knex/Postgres return boolean fields automatically as boolean values?

**EDIT:** I'm using `Knex` with `node-postgres`,
here are my table definitions:

```
knex.schema
  .createTable('users_table', (table) => {
    table.increments('id');
    table.string('email').unique().notNullable();
    table.string('full_name').notNullable();
    table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now()).notNullable();

    table.index('email', 'email_unique', 'unique');
  })
  .createTable('users_credentials', (table) => {
    table.increments('id');
    table.string('password').notNullable();
    table.boolean('is_activated').defaultTo(false).notNullable();
    table.integer('user_id').unsigned().references('users_table.id').notNullable();

    table.index('user_id', 'user_id_unique', 'unique');
  });
```

Comment: This question needs more information: 1) The Postgres driver being used 2) The table definition in Postgres and Knex. Add as update to question.

Comment: Looks like you will need to dig into this [pg-types](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types) and possibly override the parser. Though on a hunch in the query cast the boolean value as text e.g. `bool_val::text` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use the pg.types module:

```js
import { types } from "pg";

types.setTypeParser(16, (value) => { // 16 is the type enum vaue of boolean
    return Boolean(parseInt(value));
});
```

Comment: That's quite weird though. Doesn't `knex` come with a dependency on `pg` and `pg-types` out of the box?

Comment: @Bergi yes it does, what The Cubear Guy is doing is overriding the builtin parser per the instructions from here [node-og-types](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver my point is that node-pg-types comes with a [builtin boolean parser](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types/blob/master/lib/textParsers.js#L149) which should not need to be overridden. Something must have disabled that before.